# Time series storage design

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I checked the time series paper from google cloud https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series and also the scheme design of opentsdb which is based on hbase that is very similar to bigtable.

The scheme design of opentsdb uses a lot of tricks to encode the data points and row keys into wide rows so that the size of per data point is smaller. But in the paper of Google just suggests to use narrow rows.

My question is that, can I get some real benefit from opentsdb scheme design for time series storage with bigtable. And, is it true that the compression of bigtable can help me remove redundancy so that the opentsdb schema makes very little difference?

Answer (score 3):

To design schemas for your application is typically very specific to your needs.  You can have general recommendations, but you might be better served with a radically different design for your specific application.

Many of the suggestions in the StumbleUpon deck and MapR's video (below) are excelent design ideas that were not included in the Time Series paper.  To answer your questions:

1. Can I get some real benefit from opentsdb scheme design for time series storage with bigtable?

Yes - the design ideas from OpenTSDB are good ideas and are compatible with the Cloud Bigtable paper.

2. Is it true that the compression of bigtable can help me remove redundancy so that the opentsdb schema makes very little difference?

Cloud Bigtable's compression makes a big difference.  (Smaller things often compress smaller than bigger things even with redundancies.)

#### Schema Design

The Google [Time Series paper](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series) has the engineering team's recommendations in it and has the benefit many years of experience desigining with Bigtable.

Of course you should start with the [HBase and Schema Design](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#schema) and [Designing your Schema for Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design). Ian Varley's Masters Thesis [No Relation: The Mixed Blessings of Non-Relational Databases](http://ianvarley.com/UT/MR/Varley_MastersReport_Full_2009-08-07.pdf) is also worth reading.

#### Time Series Design

Cloudera has a good [chapter on Schema case studies](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase-0.98.1-cdh5.1.5/book/schema.casestudies.html) which talks about Time Series.

#### OpenTSDB design

MapR's [HBase Key Design with OpenTSDB](https://www.mapr.com/blog/hbase-key-design-opentsdb) video is short and worth watching.
Looking into OpenTSDB there is an [interesting deck](http://opentsdb.net/misc/opentsdb-hbasecon.pdf) from StumbleUpon.

Comment: Big thanks to u @les-vogel-google-devrel, I checked above links and they are quite useful for me. My question is that, though HBase and BigTable are very similar, but some subtle difference may make a big difference, e.g. HBase handles multiple-column-family rows or wide rows is much worse than Cassandra and BigTable, which I can not find any reference from Google to get some ideas to make decisions. Another concern is row key, OpenTSDB tries all its best to minimize the row key as it will affect the size of every data points, but I don't know if this can be also applied to BigTable case.

Comment: Larger rowkeys are easier to debug. Compression will help, but compression is also there for short rowkeys. I would add to user3113571 answer that if you have all the data at the time you are writing it, then a single write will go faster and use less resources than several.  Again, it all comes down to your particular application. If your data all comes in asynchronously and you access only 1 sensor at a time then narrow rows make great sense.  You don't really want to write the same row multiple times to make it wide (for most applications) -- there really isn't much advantage in that.

Answer (score 0):

In the whitepaper - [Cloud Bigtable Schema Design for Time Series Data](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series) - we recommend narrow rows for three reasons.

The first reason isn't specific to Cloud Bigtable.  We recommend narrow rows by default, with one event per row, because this makes your queries easy to implement and consequently your applications easier to develop, test and maintain.  We recommend wide rows only as an optimization where it doesn't obfuscate your queries and improves some measurable aspect of your application.

The second perspective is specific to Cloud Bigtable.  We recommend narrow rows because if you use wide rows, especially rows containing potentially unbounded numbers of events, you can easily, or unexpectedly, run into the [maximum recommended row size for Cloud Bigtable of 100MB](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#size-limits) which can lead to performance issues.

The third perspective is the observation that Apache HBase and Cloud Bigtable are different implementations of the HBase interface.  Optimizations that perform well for Apache HBase might not perform for Cloud Bigtable and vice versa.  The whitepaper encapsulate the lessons learned internally over the years runnning Bigtable at Google where it's generally found that narrow rows outperform wide rows.

Great question, deep and pertinent, thank you for asking it.

Comment: Thanks @user3113571. As for the 2nd point, in many cases the amount of data is predictably fixed, e.g. 1 data point per second, and 1 hours worth of data points per row. In such case, it is better to use wide row than narrow row? And is there any insights of cloud bigtable inner optimization so that I make the best of it. For metrics time series, every byte matters.

Comment: The way to approach this is to experiment with different schemas and dataset sizes then choose the schema that works best for your application and the metrics you're interested in.  With a managed service you can rely on the APIs and SLAs but not any inferred knowledge of the underlying implementation.  Cloud Bigtable is being actively improved and the underlying implementation will evolve over time.  The key thing with your comment is not to assume wider rows save bytes because every byte matters, experimental results are your yardstick.  Thanks for the follow up.